# R function 'stl'. How to make seasonal?

Tags: r, time-series

I want to know how to make 'seasonal' in stl function.

I guess 'trend' is diff time series.
and how to make seasonal??

in R
'stl' description is

```
which.cycle <- cycle(x)
z$seasonal <- tapply(z$seasonal, which.cycle, mean)[which.cycle]
```

and R documentation

```
fdrfourier  Calculation of the false discovery rates (FDR) for periodic expression
backgroundData  Generation of background expression set
ar1analysis     Performs AR1 fitting
fourierscore    Calculation of the Fourier score
```

AR and Fourier transform ??

Comment: Where do you use `stl`, could you please share more code? I wrote a detailed description of the STL algorithm in this paper: https://www.hydrol-earth-syst-sci.net/24/115/2020/hess-24-115-2020.html (section 3.2). You also have link to the git of the source code in the paper, where I use STL. If you specify more your question, and give us some data (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I can help you

Answer (score 1):

A time series cannot be **made** seasonal, strictly speaking. I suspect you mean extracting the seasonality pattern using the stl() function in R.

Let's consider an example of a time series measuring the maximum recorded air temperature in Dublin, Ireland from 1941 to 2019.

Here is a graph of the original time series:

```
weatherarima <- ts(mydata$maxtp, start = c(1941,11), frequency = 12)
plot(weatherarima,type="l",ylab="Temperature in Celsius")
title("Maximum Air Temperature - Dublin")
```

[image: maximum air temperature]

The **seasonal**, **trend**, and **random** components can be extracted with stl() as follows:

```
stl_weather = stl(weatherarima, "periodic")
seasonal_stl_weather   <- stl_weather$time.series[,1]
trend_stl_weather     <- stl_weather$time.series[,2]
random_stl_weather  <- stl_weather$time.series[,3]

plot(as.ts(seasonal_stl_weather))
title("Seasonal")
plot(trend_stl_weather)
title("Trend")
plot(random_stl_weather)
title("Random")
```

**Seasonal**

[image: seasonal]

**Trend**

[image: trend]

**Random**

[image: random]

As can be observed, there is clear seasonality in the weather data - given the change in temperature across seasons - but this was merely extracted from the series by using stl() - not created as such.

You might find the following to be informative: [Extracting Seasonality and Trend from Data: Decomposition Using R](https://anomaly.io/seasonal-trend-decomposition-in-r/index.html)